# How do you make a Hexagon button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a Hexagon button for a specific button in XAML code. Does somebody know how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010391/wpf-hex-grid-component

Comment: Read about Polygons in WPF - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-draw-a-closed-shape-by-using-the-polygon-element

Comment: how can i Draw On Button?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Datatemplate to change the appearance of the button, check this code:

```
 <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="305.661,0,180.661,87.258" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Polygon  Points="25,0 50,0 75,25 75,50 50,75 25,75 0,50 0,25"  Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="LightBlue"></Polygon>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```